# Updating column with unique constraint/index in Firebird in multiple rows

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, unique-index

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE (
    RCDNO              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    MASTCONNO          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ROWNO              INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    EDITTIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP
)
ALTER TABLE SCHEDULE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SCHEDULE PRIMARY KEY (RCDNO);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_SCHEDULE_3 ON SCHEDULE (MASTCONNO, ROWNO);
```

I can run a query like this:

```
select mastconno, rowno, rcdno, edittimestamp
from schedule
where mastconno = 12
order by rowno desc
```

and I get this:

[image]

Due to a bug in the app code, the time portion of the edittimestamp is missing but that's of no consequence here. The records are nonetheless listed in desc order of entry by ROWNO. That's what the design of this table is meant to facilitate.

What I tried to do is this...

```
update SCHEDULE
set ROWNO = (ROWNO + 1)
where MASTCONNO = 12
```

... in preparation for the insert of a new ROWNO=0 record, I get this error:

```
attempt to store duplicate value (visible to active transactions) in unique index "IDX_SCHEDULE_3".
Problematic key value is ("MASTCONNO" = 12, "ROWNO" = 3).
```

Incidently I have an exact copy of the table in MS SQL Server, and I didn't have this problem there. This seems to be specific to the way Firebird works.

So then I tried this, hoping that Firebird would "feed" values from the `IN` predicate to the `UPDATE` in a non-offending order.

```
update SCHEDULE
set ROWNO = (ROWNO + 1)
where MASTCONNO = 12 and 
ROWNO in (select ROWNO from SCHEDULE 
where MASTCONNO = 12 order by ROWNO DESC)
```

Sadly the response was the same as before. ROWNO 3 is being duplicated by the update statement.

Comment: What is your firebird version? do you have warranty, that no any other application would insert new records, when you change the table ? usually SQL is used for many users

Comment: For the record, I am using 2.5

Answer (score 3):

With the unique index (MASTCONNO, ROWNO) in place, I have tested the following:

```
update SCHEDULE
set ROWNO = (ROWNO + 1)
where MASTCONNO = 12
order by ROWNO DESC
```

Works correctly!

```
update SCHEDULE
set ROWNO = (ROWNO - 1)
where MASTCONNO = 12
order by ROWNO ASC
```

Also works correctly!

Thanks very much Mark Rotteveel.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, constraint checks and triggers Firebird runs per every row, not per transaction or per table.

So you would have to use the same loop-based approach you use in applications dealing with lists and arrays.

You have to use `EXECUTE BLOCK` and a properly directed loop.

http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html

You take MAXimum ID that is of interest, and increment it.
Then you take previous value. 
Then previous...

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS
  DECLARE ID INTEGER;
BEGIN
  ID = ( SELECT MAX(ROWNO) FROM SCHEDULE WHERE MASTCONNO = 12 );

/* 
  ID = NULL;
  SELECT MAX(ROWNO) FROM SCHEDULE WHERE MASTCONNO = 12 INTO :ID;
  IF (ID IS NULL) raise-some-error-somehow
*/
  While (ID >= 0)
  Begin
    update SCHEDULE set ROWNO = (ID + 1)
       where MASTCONNO = 12 and :ID = ROWNO;
    ID = ID - 1;
  End
END
```

DANGER!

If while you started are doing it some another transaction (maybe from another program working at another computer) inserts some new row with `MASTCONNO = 12` and commits it - you have problems.

Firebird is multi-versions server, not table-blocking server, so there will be nothing in server, that prohibits this insert because your procedure is working on the table. Then you have race conditions, the fastest transaction would commit itself, and the slower one would fail with unique index violation.

You may also use FOR-SELECT loop instead of WHILE loop.

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-forselect

Like this

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT * FROM SCHEDULE 
      WHERE MASTCONNO = 12 
      ORDER BY ROWNO DESCENDING  -- proper loop direction: ordering is key!
      AS CURSOR PTR 
  DO
    UPDATE SCHEDULE SET ROWNO = ROWNO + 1
      WHERE CURRENT OF PTR;
END
```

However, in Firebird 3 cursors-based positioning became rather slow.

Comment: Thanks. As for the issue of multiple users trying to do the same thing at the same time, this would be a very unusual situation as the table in question is a "master" that is only updated once a month, and by a supervisor who knows to do it when others are not using the table for anything. He will ensure exclusive access to the table.

Comment: IIRC an update with an `order by rowno descending` might also do the trick, I believe it will do an ordered update of the rows. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Mark, WOW! did not know about it! At least in Firebird 2.5 it should do the trick as well. Make an answer, it would be much better than mine. @nolaspeaker look into - https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-update.html#fblangref25-dml-update-orderbyclause

Comment: That update with order by looks very interesting. I will test it now.

Comment: I see @nolaspeaker has already posted an answer. It was just a guess in the back of my mind, and I didn't have time to validate it yet, luckily nolaspeaker already has.